# Does the Worker constructor accept relative urls?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, web-worker

I wonder if the `Worker` constructor from accept relative paths. For example, having a file structure like this:

```
root/
+---js/
|   +--workers/
|   |  +--some-worker.js
|   +--index.js
+---index.html
```

If `index.html` loads `index.js` and `index.js` does something like this:

```
var someWorker = new Worker("./workers/some-worker.js");
```

Will this work fine? Well, no. The strange thing is that it resolves the url to `<domain>/workers/some-worker.js`.

Is there a solution for this issue? I expected to load `<domain>/js/workers/some-worker.js` instead.

How to make `new Worker("workers/some-worker.js")` to resolve to the relative directory (in this example `/js/workers/some-worker.js`, since it was called from `/js/`)?

Comment: Nopes. It has to be the absolute relative URL from the domain!

Comment: @PraveenKumar Then, the workaround would be to get the script url and create the absolute `Worker` url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use relative URLs for this. The other thing is that, it accepts relative URLs as relative to the domain. So, it is either:

- Absolute URLs
- Relative URLs to Domain

Nothing other than these. You can refer [MDN `Worker()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Worker) for more information.

Also you do have a workaround, by setting the URL by getting the current location. So you do this instead:

```
var someWorker = new Worker(location.href + "/workers/some-worker.js");
```

Or to be precise, you can do this:

```
currentPath = location.href.split("#");
if (currentPath.length > 1)
  currentPath = currentPath[0];
currentPath = location.href.split("?");
if (currentPath.length > 1)
  currentPath = currentPath[0];
var someWorker = new Worker(currentPath + "/workers/some-worker.js");
```

Hope this helps! `:)`

Comment: I agree, but `location.href` will return the page url, not the script url.